# Apps script html service whitespace at top

Tags: css, google-apps-script

I have a simple script that displays a html file

```
function doGet(e) {
     return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Final Contract Agreement').evaluate();
}
```

and the corrasponing html:

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <style type="text/css">
     #content{
          padding :0 0;
          margin : 0 auto;
          width: 800px;
          height : 600px;
          background: #FFFFFF;
     }
     body{
         background: #dbdad4;
         margin : 0;
     }
     #header{
         width: 100%;
         height: 82px;
         background: #4F2170;
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
     }
     #header h1{
         vertical-align:middle;
         text-align:right;
         color: white;
         padding-right: 50px;
     }
     </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="header">
      <h1>
         Contract Form
      </h1>
     </div>
    <div id="content">
       <h3>
        Hello World! 
        <?= new Date() ?>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

it ouputs this:

[image: whitespace]

I have tried setting all combinations of margins/paddings on the elements but nothing is getting rid of the whitespace on top. When i put the same code in a plane jane html file it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing the caja is adding the whitespace to the top, this css removed the whitespace for me:

```
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
```

also for those wondering this is how i got it to take up the whole browser window:

```
  html {
    height:100%;
  }
  body{
    height:100%;
  }
```